# Не преобразовывая структуру данных, вычислить на ее основе с помощью lapply() преобладающее направление для каждого месяца

Tags: dataframe, r

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть следующий датафрейм, требуется не преобразовывая структуру данных, вычислить на ее основе с помощью lapply() преобладающее направление для каждого месяца.

Узнать максимальную величину не составит труда, только вот как можно это совместить с колонкой направлений?

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: видимо, вам нужно что-то примерно такое: `lapply(ваш.tibble[,1:2+1], function(v) ваш.tibble[[which.max(v),1]])`